# What is $P(A \cup(B \cap C))$?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

> What is $P(A \cup(B \cap C))$?

The question says it all.  I know $$P(A \cap (B \cup C))=P(A \cap B)+P(A \cap C).$$  Would this mean, $$P(A \cup(B \cap C))=P(A \cup B)+P(A \cup C)?$$  Just want to make sure.

Comment: By "I know $P(A\cap (B\cup C))=P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap C)$", do you mean that it's a hypothesis you have been given, or do you mean that you believe said statement to be true for all $A$, $B$, $C$?

Comment: What does $+$ mean here?

Comment: $P(A\cap (B\cup C))$ is *not* equal to $P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap C)$.  That is incorrect.  What *is* correct is that $P(A\cap (B\cup C)) = P((A\cap B)\cup (A\cap C)) = P(A\cap B) + P(A\cup C)\color{red}{-P(A\cap B\cap C)}$

Comment: @healynr It means $+$, like in $\frac12+\frac13$

Comment: @Gae.S. Oh! I thought this was referring to power sets not probability! Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The equation 
$$
P(A\cup (B\cap C))=P(A\cup B)+P(A\cup C)
$$
will almost certainly not hold. This is because
$$
P(A\cup (B \cap C))=P((A\cup B)\cap (A\cup C))\leq P(A\cup B)
$$
and similarly
$$
P(A\cup (B \cap C))\leq P(A\cup C).
$$
For the stated equation to hold, both $P(A\cup B)$ and $P(A\cup C)$ would have to be zero, showing that 
$$
P(A)=P(B)=P(C)=0.
$$
However, if this condition is satisfied, then the stated equation will hold.

Answer (score 0):

Things to remember:

- Intersection "distributes" over unions.

$$X\cap (Y\cup Z) = (X\cap Y)\cup (X\cap Z)$$

*Note:* This should remind you how $a\cdot (b+c)=(a\cdot b)+(a\cdot c)$ with multiplication and addition.

- Unions also distribute over intersections.

$$X\cup (Y\cap Z) = (X\cup Y)\cap (X\cup Z)$$

- Probabilities of a union of events can expand via inclusion-exclusion:

$$Pr(X\cup Y)=Pr(X)+Pr(Y)-Pr(X\cap Y)$$

*Note:* when $X\cap Y$ occurs with probability zero, for example when $X$ and $Y$ are mutually exclusive/disjoint events then this simplifies as $Pr(X\cup Y)=Pr(X)+Pr(Y)$.  In general however this is not the case and their intersection is non-trivial so you must not forget the final term being subtracted.

- Probabilities of an intersection can expand via product rule:

$$Pr(X\cap Y)=Pr(X)\times Pr(Y\mid X)$$

*Note:* The term on the right, $Pr(Y\mid X)$ is a conditional probability and is in general *not* equal to $Pr(Y)$.  Only when $X$ and $Y$ are independent events will you have $Pr(Y\mid X)$ can simplify to $Pr(Y)$ in which case the above can be rewritten to be $Pr(X\cap Y)=Pr(X)\times Pr(Y)$.  Without knowledge of whether or not $X$ and $Y$ are dependent on one another or independent of one another, we cannot make that simplification.

So, in other words, union inside of probability acts "*like*" addition outside of probability while intersection inside of probability acts "*like*" multiplication outside of probability... though again with those extra considerations and warnings mentioned above.

---

Now, we have that

$$\begin{array}{rll}Pr(A\cap (B\cup C)) &= Pr((A\cap B)\cup (A\cap C))&\text{by distributivity}\\&=Pr(A\cap B)+Pr(A\cap C)-Pr((A\cap B)\cap (A\cap C))&\text{by inclusion-exlcusion}\\&=Pr(A\cap B)+Pr(A\cap C)-Pr(A\cap B\cap C)&\text{by associativity and absorption}\end{array}$$

So, when you say "*I know that...*", if that was your attempt to cite some identity that you learned, you learned it incorrectly and had forgotten to subtract the final piece.

If you say "*I know that...*" as though it were a given *hypothesis*, then by the above we would learn that $Pr(A\cap B\cap C)$ is equal to zero by comparing what it should have been equal to against what you are told it was equal to.

As for the other identity,

$$\begin{array}{rll}Pr(A\cup (B\cap C))&=Pr(A)+Pr(B\cap C)-Pr(A\cap (B\cap C))&\text{by inclusion-exclusion}\\&=Pr(A)+Pr(B\cap C)-Pr(A\cap B\cap C)&\text{by associativity}\end{array}$$

You could have if you insisted broken apart a different way:

$$\begin{array}{rll}Pr(A\cup (B\cap C))&=Pr((A\cup B)\cap (A\cup C))\\&=Pr(A\cup B)\times Pr((A\cup C)\mid (A\cup B))\end{array}$$

but this seems very unhelpful.